# CakePHP: multiple installations on single domain; login session sharing issue

Tags: session, cakephp

I’ve installed CakePHP into sub-directories and they seem to run fine! They all have different **database.php** configuration files and access different databases.

Example:

1. public_html/cakephp1/
2. public_html/cakephp2/

I access them separately using http://www.example.com/cakephp1/ and http://www.example.com/cakephp2/ and it all seems fine.

Problem occurs when I log into one of them (using CakePHP standard `Auth`/`Session` components), and I when I flip over to the other installation it also considers me as already logged in!

How do I prevent this? What’s the recommended solution? Will it help if I change the `salt` value in each installation?

**EDIT:**

Hi Martin, I've just tried the method of changing core.php  to use "cake" session handling and specifying a cookie path. So now in each application i have different core.php files as such:

cakephp1's core.php

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'cake',
        'ini' => array(
            'session.cookie_path' => '/cakephp1'
        )
    ));
```

cakephp2's core.php

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'cake',
        'ini' => array(
            'session.cookie_path' => '/cakephp2'
        )
    ));
```

But still does not work and both installs seem to still share the same session. Where should I be looking to see if a cookie was actually created? I've checked the folder tmp/sessions under each /cakephp1 and /cakephp2 but that folder is always empty.

**EDIT: Modifying AppController:**

Martin, please help me suggest where else to look. I've followed ur code as follows:

Below is the code from my /demo/ installation (resides at public_html/demo/)
**Can you tell me where I can find the cookie that is supposed to be created with your code?**

If it is supposed to be at public_html/demo/app/tmp/sessions, I see nothing there even after logging in. There is also nothing under public_html/demo/ other than standard CakePHP folders.

This is from my AppController for the /demo/ installation which is accessed via http://www.example.com/demo/ as opposed to the other installation which is at http://www.example.com/tst/

```
public $components = array(
    //'DebugKit.Toolbar',
   'Cookie',
   'Session',
    'Auth'=>array(
     //Stuff
    )
}

public function beforeFilter() {
    //Logic placed here will run before the action is run
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Cookie->path = '/demo/';        

}
```

The core.php is set as default which is:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php'
));
```

Answer (score 2):

You’ll need to restrict cookies in each of your applications to their respective sub-directories. For example, in your **AppController.php** you can do this in a `beforeFilter()` action:

```
<?php

class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'Cookie',
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Cookie->path = '/cakephp1/';
    }

}
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html#controller-setup for more details.

Comment: Hi Martin, I've tried your method for AppController and its still sharing sessions. I really have no idea where to look :(

Comment: Thanks for the response Martin. Yes i did clear cookies in my browser. I've edited the end of my post to show u what exactly my AppController and Core.php look like. Where am i supposed to find the cookies?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue.

Use below code for first cakephp application in core.php / bootstrap.php

> Configure::write('Security.cookie', 'cakephp1');

while in second cakephp application use the below code in core.php / bootstrap.php

> Configure::write('Security.cookie', 'cakephp2');

Comment: Hi there, i tried the code, added "Cookie" to the $components array so it didn't spit out any errors. It doesn't work and still shares sessions between different installs. Am i missing something? Is there something special I need to do in htaccess ?

Comment: check the updated answer , i hope your query gets resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed my problem.

I had a session_start() php commandsomewhere in my code which overwrote all the core.php config, and basically it restored the php.ini session management settings.

[CakePHP Session being written to /tmp/ and not /app/tmp/sessions/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396811/cakephp-session-being-written-to-tmp-and-not-app-tmp-sessions/25400740#25400740)

Answer (score 0):

Although there are answers that talk about cookies but don't mention about using Cake's own session or PHP's session. So, I thought it'd be good to share a documented way of achieving this.

CakePHP (at least 2.x), by default uses `php` session settings from `php.ini`.

The setting can be found in `/app/Config/core.php` and well documented there:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php' // possible values: php, cake, database, cache
));
```

For apps with own [cake installation directory](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html), it is as simple as changing the above value to `cake` which tells the app to use `app/tmp/sessions` for saving session files. It is imperative to mention that a different cookie name for each installation may be needed:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake'
    'cookie' => 'myApp1' // something like 'myApp2' for other app
));
```

[Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html) has good documentation on all settings related to sessions.